# How to use the Web Interface of Confluent Control Center?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I deployed confluent on a Single cloud on a Linux VM and I'm planning to configure interceptors for the Consumers.
But how do I configure Control Center in order to access its Web-Interface?

Deployed Confluent Control Center Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what issues you're having.

Edit the `server.properties` file. Add the bootstrap servers, Zookeeper quorum, and optionally the connect cluster.

With that, you should at least be able to see the topics in the cluster

Run the `control-center` binary with the server property file as a parameter.

See additional setup steps required for the clients to get monitoring to work at [the documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/docs/installation/clients.html#installing-control-center-interceptors)